# How to create dynamic html with content in angular js controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to create dynamic html content to display data into view from controller i tried with following code to display data but it replacing old data with new data

```
var checklen = Math.random();
$http.post("getnotifierdis",{"postid":postid,"postreplyid":postrplyid}).then(function(result)
        {
           $scope.datas = result;
           appendedHtml = 
            '<div class="notifier notice'+checklen+'"  id="{{postreplyid}}" style="margin-top:'+toppos+'">'
              +'<div class="replyhere">'
                  +'<div class="col-sm-11 no-padding">{{datas.reply}}</div>'
                  +'<div class="col-sm-1 no-padding"><a ng-click="gotothisdis(postid,postreplyid)"><img src="images/discussicons/plugsb.png" class="newiconssmalls" /></a></div>'
                  +'<div class="clearfix"></div>'
              +'</div>'
              +'<div class="margin6"></div>' 
                 +'<div class="timeago">'
                     +'<div class="col-sm-11 no-padding">{{datas.timing}} ago</div>'
                     +'<div class="col-sm-1  no-padding"><a ng-click="removethisnot(postreplyid)"><img src="images/discussicons/wrongb.png" class="newiconssmalls" /></a></div>'
                 +'<div class="clearfix"></div>'
                +'</div>' 
            +'</div>';
           el = document.getElementById('desknotification');
           angular.element(el).append( $compile(appendedHtml)($scope) );
           $("#desknotification div#"+checklen).fadeIn(500); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to create a div in this manner:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in arrayPost">
   <div  ng-class="'notifier notice'+ post.checklen"
         id="{{post.postreplyid}}" ng-style="margin-top:'+post.toppos">
          <div class="replyhere">
              <div class="col-sm-11 no-padding">{{post.datas.reply}}   </div>
              <div class="col-sm-1 no-padding"><a ng-click="gotothisdis({{post.postid}},{{post.postreplyid}})"><img src="images/discussicons/plugsb.png" class="newiconssmalls" /></a></div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="margin6"></div>
             <div class="timeago">
                <div class="col-sm-11 no-padding">{{post.datas.timing}} ago</div>
                 <div class="col-sm-1  no-padding"><a ng-click="removethisnot({{post.postreplyid}})"><img src="images/discussicons/wrongb.png" class="newiconssmalls" /></a></div>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in your controller do this:

```
var checklen = Math.random();

$scope.arrayPost = []
$http.post("getnotifierdis",{"postid":postid,"postreplyid":postrplyid}).then(function(result)
    {
       var newPost = {}
       newPost.datas = result;

       newPost.checklen = your value;
       newPost.postreplyid = your id;
       newPost.toppos = your value;

       arrayPost.push(newPost)
        .....
    });
```

Comment: but when new data will be added then last data will be replaced with new data

Comment: @vikasvyas I modified the response with ng-repeat.